# Error when using php include function

Tags: php

I'm working on a php web application under windows. I have many script files placed in their respective folders and all the files needs a file named 'connexion.php' that is situated in the root project.

The structure of the project is as follow:
Projet_beta :

```
  -client (folder):
          *addClient.php
          *modifyClient.php
          *deleteClient.php

  - connexion.php
```

So, when i use `include ('../connexion.php')` inside the 'addClient.php' it displays this error message :

> Warning: include(connexion.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\project_beta\client\addClient.php on line 3.

How can i fix this problem ? 
Thank's every one.

Comment: Does this server do any URL rewriting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your `httpd.conf` file :

1. left click on wamp
2. php menu
3. open the `httpd.conf` file
4. Find the line starting with `DocumentRoot`
5. Change the line to `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"` and save the file
6. Restart wamp services

Then use :

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/project_beta/connexion.php');
```

Comment: Thank you Brewal for your answer.

Comment: I used 'echo' to display the result of dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'connexion.php'; it displayes me : C:/wamp\connexion.php or my file connexion.php is in : c:\wamp\www\project_beta\ !

Comment: It seems that your `httpd.conf` is not well configured. I will edit my answer.

Comment: In that document, i have : DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/" it seems good and i do not know how can i fix the issue in the httpd.conf

Comment: Try removing the `dirname` function, then echo the path.

Comment: Thank's very much for your insights Brewel and for every one. I just ommited the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR in the include function : include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'project_beta/connexion.php');   because with the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR included it displays this: C:/wamp/www/\coplayers_backoffice/connexion.php and we have to use the include function with out DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

Answer (score 1):

Try this include ('/../connexion.php')

The extra slash should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dirname func :

```
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/connexion.php"));
```

Comment: EoiFirst: i had this message : Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\project_beta) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\project_beta\clients.php

Comment: The issue is still remaining even with your responses that i had tried out. Is there any other alternative to fix this issue? Thank's again.

Comment: I haven't done php since long time so my answer might not be perfect. I remember that i faced the same problem once, and dirname function helped me to solve it. Try to read the doc about it : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.dirname.php

Comment: thank's very much, i will read this document and try to fix it.

Comment: the problem is still remaining and i'm searching for the solution since 2 hours ago, is there any one who had the same problem in the past and fixed it ? I thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Should use

```
dirname(__FILE__)."../connexion.php"
```

instead. 
In this case, "../" search files from the path you executing the file, not the real path of the file.

Answer (score -1):

Windows versions of PHP prior to PHP 4.3.0 do not support access of remote files via this function, even if allow_url_fopen is enabled.

Comment: the version of my php is 5.3.13